# Docker run start services

Tags: nginx, docker, redis, dockerfile

I need nginx-openresty and  redis in single docker container. I have written docker file its working fine. But thing  i need to start my redis service after login into the docker bash to automate this I have written  .sh file which contains instrutions like  start and stop of redis server and nginx. `ENTRYPOINT ["./startup.sh"]`

and .sh file is

```
cd /etc/redis-installation/utils
echo -n | ./install_server.sh
service redis_6379 stop
cd /
cp ./dump.rdb /var/lib/redis/6379/
service redis_6379 start
openresty
```

My problem is that docker container start and exist when shell execution completed. How can stay the container keep running with nginx and redis in  running state.

Comment: Why do you need them in the same container?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) with a [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) between your app container and your redis container. I suggest using the [official redis container](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/)